# Read/write request parameters before Servlet in Tomcat 7 

Tags: tomcat

Is there any way in Tomcat 7 to read and modify GET and POST request parameters before the Servlet is called?

So far I have found the Valve and Filter concepts but in my case they have several problems:

1) There seems to be no way to send a response right from the Valve/Filter without calling  Servlet

2) Request Dumper Valve was removed from Tomcat 7, so if I want to process request parameters only for one application I need to use Filter.

3) How can I safely change the request parameters?

Is there any solution? A code sample would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> *1) There seems to be no way to send a response right from the Valve/Filter without calling Servlet*

That's not true. Just write to the `response.getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` directly without continuing the valve/filter chain (i.e. do **not** call `chain.doFilter(req, res)`).

---

> *2) Request Dumper Valve was removed from Tomcat 7, so if I want to process request parameters only for one application I need to use Filter.*

This has indeed been replaced by [`RequestDumperFilter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/RequestDumperFilter.html) which allows you to register it at webapp level instead of at server level (i.e. in your webapp's `web.xml`). See also [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter).

---

I'm only not sure how exactly the above is related to modifying the request. But for the case that, there you normally use [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) for.